# Why are checkboxes getting cleared when I edit an entry through Safecracker?

Tags: expressionengine, safecracker

Why are checkboxes getting cleared when I edit my entries in Safecracker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the parameter
    preserve_checkboxes="yes"

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#preserve-checkboxes